# vaadin grid inline number format

Tags: grid, format, vaadin

I am using

```
    NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    format.setGroupingUsed(true);

    NumberRenderer numPointCommaRenderer = new NumberRenderer(format); 
    pnGrid.getColumn("amount").setRenderer(numPointCommaRenderer);
```

in order to display in a vaadin grid the number "1.234,56"  but when i enter in the inline mode the number is changing with the default locale "1,234.56".
I don't want to change the default locale (English) also i don't to alter the locale of the grid.

only to alter the inline edit of the number to "1,234.56".
Any suggestions

Elias

Comment: With 'inline mode' do you mean the editing mode? If so please provide the code of your 'amount' field and the binding.

Comment: As @AxelMeier says, you should provide little more info. But, if is edit mode what you are saying, you have to set column's `editorField` and set the locale of that field.